# new response.listener is not working in StringRequest

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to send my PHP page a parameter to get an array of rows from my database.
I'm using Volley and checked my PHP pages working in POSTMAN and get the excepted result.
the problem is nothing happens in Android. when I'm debugging I see the program is not getting into new Response.Listener at all.
it jumps straight to the end of the function. will be happy to get some advices
here is my code:

```
package il.reportap;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.loginregister.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.time.Clock;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class InboxDoctor extends AppCompatActivity {

       // private static final String URL = "http://androidcodefinder.com/RecyclerViewJson.json";
    private URLs url;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private List<ModelActivity> modelActivityList;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.inbox_doctor);

            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            modelActivityList = new ArrayList<>();

            loadData();
        }

        private void loadData() {

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url.URL_INBOXDR,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() { //program not get in here
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            try {
                                //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                    JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    ModelActivity modelActivity = new ModelActivity(
                                            o.getString("sentTime"),
                                            o.getString("patientId"),
                                            o.getString("testName"),
                                            o.getBoolean("date")
                                    );
                                    modelActivityList.add(modelActivity);
                                }

                                adapter = new AdapterActivity(modelActivityList, getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                            } catch (JSONException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() { //goes here and do nothing
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
            {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("department", String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUser().getDepartment()));
                    System.out.println(params.get("department"));
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
}
```

edited:
my PHP code:
operations:

```
function inboxdr($department)
    {
        $response = array();
        $query="SELECT M.sent_time, M.patient_ID, T.name, M.is_urgent FROM messages as M JOIN test_types as T ON M.test_type=T.ID WHERE M.recipient_dept = ? AND M.confirm_time IS NULL";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $department);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows=$stmt->num_rows;

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

            while ($rows>0){
            $stmt->bind_result($sentTime, $patientId, $testName, $isUrgent);
            $stmt->fetch();
            
            $report[$stmt->num_rows-$rows] = array(
                'sent_time' => $sentTime,
                'patient_id' => $patientId,
                'name' => $testName,
                'is_urgent' => $isUrgent,
            );
            $rows--;
        }
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = 'new report for you';
            $response['report'] = $report;
        } else {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'שגיאה בהצגת הדיווח';
        }
        return $response;
```

API: that's only a switch case so that's the relevant piece of code

```
 case 'inboxdr':
            $response = isTheseParametersAvailable(array('department'));
            if (!$response['error']){
                $response=$oper->inboxdr($_POST['department']);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: if it goes into the error listener (as you said in your comment), then what is the error response

Comment: it's not. it goes to new ResponseListener <String>
and not get into it, just go back to the line StringRequest, go down to the Error, and not get into it as well.. back again to the StringRequest, and then it's just going to the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think response is not converted to JSONArray correctly. I would suggest you use  JsonObjectRequest like this.

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("department", String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUser().getDepartment()));

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( url,new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("your result Json array name");
                    
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                ModelActivity modelActivity = new ModelActivity(
                                        o.getString("sentTime"),
                                        o.getString("patientId"),
                                        o.getString("testName"),
                                        o.getBoolean("date")
                                );
                                modelActivityList.add(modelActivity);
                            }

                            adapter = new AdapterActivity(modelActivityList, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) { 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
              RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Also to catch your JsonObject in Php use this piece of code

```
// Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$key = json_decode($json);

$department = $key->department;
```

**PHP code for coverting result into Json array**

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    array_push($result,array('first_name'=>$row[3],
    
    'sentTime'=>$row[1], //column number in database
    'patientId'=>$row[2],
    'testName'=>$row[3],
    'date'=>$row[4]
     ));
}
 
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

put your result in mysqli_fetch_array($res) and assign it to $row in while loop.Now put your array in array_push($result, array()) and inside array() make key pair values with $row[] according to column in database (first column starts with 0);

If you try this approach make sure you return response from PHP as JsonArray with appropriate name and use that name in `response.getJSONARRAY("Here")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure how should I convert my array in PHP to the piece of code you wrote here. Well I'll try and hopefully it will work :)

Comment: @YaelA. I have edited answer to convert you array

Comment: Thank you very much!!